# Detecting header in HTML tables using beautifulsoup / lxml when table lacks thead element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'd like to detect the header of an HTML table when that table does not have `<thead>` elements. (MediaWiki, which drives Wikipedia, [does not support `<thead>` elements](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#Common_attributes_for_columns.2C_column_groups_and_row_groups).) I'd like to do this with python in both BeautifulSoup and lxml. Let's say I already have a `table` object and I'd like to get out of it a `thead` object, a `tbody` object, and a `tfoot` object.

Currently, `parse_thead` does the following when the `<thead>` tag is present:

- In BeautifulSoup, I get table objects with `doc.find_all('table')` and I can use `table.find_all('thead')`
- In lxml, I get table objects with `doc.xpath()` on an xpath_expr on `//table`, and I can use `table.xpath('.//thead')`

and `parse_tbody` and `parse_tfoot` work in the same way. (I did not write this code and I am not experienced with either BS or lxml.) However, without a `<thead>`, `parse_thead` returns nothing and `parse_tbody` returns the header and the body together.

I append a [wikitable instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_England_Test_cricket_records#Most_extras_in_one_inning) below as an example. It lacks `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. Instead all rows, header or not, are enclosed in `<tr>...</tr>`, but header rows have `<th>` elements and body rows have `<td>` elements. Without `<thead>`, it seems like the right criterion for identifying the header is "from the start, put rows into the header until you find a row that has an element that's not `<th>`".

I'd appreciate suggestions on how I could write `parse_thead` and `parse_tbody`. Without much experience here, I would think I could either

- Dive into the table object and manually insert `thead` and `tbody` tags before parsing it (this seems nice because then I wouldn't have to change any other code that recognizes tables with `<thead>`), or alternately
- Change `parse_thead` and `parse_tbody` to recognize the table rows that have only `<th>` elements. (With either alternative, it seems like I really need to detect the head-body boundary in this way.)

I don't know how to do either of those things and I'd appreciate advice on both which alternative is more sensible and how I might go about it.

(Edit: Examples with [no header rows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Twenty20_International_records#Highest_innings_totals) and [multiple header rows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Cricket_World_Cup_records#One_tournament). I can't assume it has only one header row.)

```
<table class="wikitable">
<tr>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Score</th>
<th>Overs</th>
<th><b>Ext</b></th>
<th>b</th>
<th>lb</th>
<th>w</th>
<th>nb</th>
<th>Opposition</th>
<th>Ground</th>
<th>Match Date</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>437</td>
<td>136.0</td>
<td><b>64</b></td>
<td>18</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>v West Indies</td>
<td>Manchester</td>
<td>27 Jul 1995</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the header for this table ?

Comment: The first `<tr>` marks the header because that row has only `<th>`s in it. That's how Mediawiki formats it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_England_Test_cricket_records#Most_extras_in_one_inning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `<th>` tags to detect headers, in case the table doesn't contain `<thead>` tags. If all columns of a row are `<th>` tags then we can assume that it is a header. Based on that I created a function that identifies the header and body.

Code for `BeautifulSoup`:

```
def parse_table(table): 
    head_body = {'head':[], 'body':[]}
    for tr in table.select('tr'): 
        if all(t.name == 'th' for t in tr.find_all(recursive=False)): 
            head_body['head'] += [tr]
        else: 
            head_body['body'] += [tr]
    return head_body
```

Code for `lxml`:

```
def parse_table(table): 
    head_body = {'head':[], 'body':[]}
    for tr in table.cssselect('tr'): 
        if all(t.tag == 'th' for t in tr.getchildren()): 
            head_body['head'] += [tr]
        else: 
            head_body['body'] += [tr]
    return head_body
```

The `table` parameter is either a Beautiful Soup Tag object or a lxml Element object. `head_body` is a dictionary that contains two lists of `<tr>` tags, the header and body rows.

Usage example:

```
html = '<table><tr><th>heade</th></tr><tr><td>body</td></tr></table>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = parse_table(table)

print(table_rows)
#{'head': [<tr><th>header</th></tr>], 'body': [<tr><td>body</td></tr>]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with XPath <sup>[W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)</sup> will hopefully be more general. Note there is no namespace included, which may be necessary depending on your environment. This answer was verified with [this xpath tester](https://extendsclass.com/xpath-tester.html) linked from MDN.

***** For the below, assuming XPath relative to the table, i.e. you are calling an xpath function on a `<table>` element and therefore `.` is a `<table>`; alternatively you could prepend `//table//` to the paths.

## Example

The following is in Python using lxml<sup>[1]</sup> as that is what is mentioned in the question. `parse_thead` returns `<tr>` elements that are children of the supplied node, and have only `<th>` cells. `parse_tbody` returns `<tr>` elements that have at least one `<td>` cell:

```python
_TR_HEADER = './/tr[count(th)=count(th|td)]'
_TR_BODY = './/tr[count(th)<count(th|td)]'
def parse_thead(table):
    return table.xpath(_TR_HEADER)
def parse_tbody(table):
    return table.xpath(_TR_BODY)
```

It should be relatively straightforward to default to looking for the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements before falling back on this strategy.

Handling malformed HTML tables is harder though, and would probably require some pre- and post-processing if you are restricted to XPath 1.0.

## Explanation

To select "header" table rows (`<tr>` elements) where all children are `<th>` elements:

```python
_TR_HEADER = '//tr[count(th)=count(*)'
```

To select "body" table rows where there is at least one child that is not a `<th>`:

```python
_TR_BODY = '//tr[count(th)<count(*)'
```

## Refinements

- Only select rows as headers if there are no `<td>` cells:

  ```python
  _TR_HEADER = '//tr[count(td)=0]'
  ```
- Always select the first row as a header if no rows meet the requirement<sup>[2]</sup>:

  ```python
  _TR_HEADER = '//tr[..[count(tr[count(th)=count(*)])=0] and position()=1 or count(th)=count(*)]'
  ```
- Always select rows that appear in a `<thead>` tag in addition to rows that meet the requirement:

  ```python
  _TR_HEADER = '//tr[count(th)=count(*) or ..[name()="thead"]]
  ```
- Select rows as body that have at most one `<th>` and at least one `<td>`:

  ```python
  _TR_BODY = '//tr[count(th)<2 and count(td)>1]
  ```
- Select rows as body if there are no headers, or if they appear following a header<sup>[2]</sup>:

  ```python
  _TR_BODY = '//tr[..[count(tr[count(th)=count(*)])=0] or preceding-sibling::tr[count(th)=count(*)] and count(th)<count(*)]'
  ```
- Select rows as body if they follow the last header row as defined in the question:

  ```python
  _TR_BODY = '//tr[count(th)=count(th|td)][last()]/following-sibling::tr
  ```

## Caveats

- There is no namespace information, which may be required in some environments.
- There are some assumptions about well-formed tables in the above, which may fail if there are e.g. spans or similar wrapping the row or cell elements.
- This answer assumes that the tables - as specified in the question - contain only `<th>` cells in the header rows, and at least one `<td>` in body rows.
- It also may not have the desired behavior when used on nested tables. Adding predicates to find the initial `<table>` or the prepended path could help, as could specifying intermediate nodes such as `<tbody>` instead of using `//`.
- It also does not specifically handle `row-span` and `col-span` attributes, although that can be done by post-processing elements selected.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Note this may require supplying `namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` as a named parameter to the `{node}.xpath` calls, I think depending on the parser you use.

<sup>[2]</sup> Note this is messy because there's no `sibling-or-self` to count on, hence `..[count(...)]`. I limited the answer to XPath 1.0 since features from XPath 2.0 and onwards are not always supported. Additionally using `parent` breaks in the case there is a `<thead>` wrapping. Running an alternate selection if the original path returns no nodes would be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify if the `tr` tag contains the `th` child you want, `candidate.th` returns `None` if there's no `th` inside `candidate`:

```
possibleHeaders = soup.find("table").findAll("tr")
    
Headers = []
for candidate in possibleHeaders:
    if candidate.th:
        Headers.append(candidate)
```

Comment: Could be multiple rows, sad to say. Certainly there are lots of wikipedia tables with multiple header rows. (And tables with no header rows.)

Comment: Oh, I see, then could you provide an example page when that's then case?

Comment: Here's one with two rows: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Cricket_World_Cup_records#One_tournament

Comment: Here's one with no rows: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Twenty20_International_records#Highest_innings_totals

Comment: Well, my solution will work for tables with more than one row, but certainly not for one with no header rows at all, note that even though there's no proper header, the first column is encapsulated in <th>, so it could be considered a header to the code.

Comment: I think the criterion for "is a header row" for wikitables needs to be "all elements within that row are `<th>`", not just some. It's OK to put `<th>` as a left-side header (I'm sure it has a better name than that) within a body row.

Comment: @jowens Ah, thats an important piece of information, I'll edit my answer to suit the question better then!

Comment: That's just my guess of the code that will work, anyway. Your input helpful on that! Also your advice on my two suggestions for how I might structure the big-picture code (bottom of my original question)?

Comment: @jowens Well, the big-picture code for extracting could be just get all `tables` and then running the script for finding headers, what is not a header, certainly is your body of the table, or have I missed something? About the script, I developed an **insanely** hacky way to make it work for no rows cases. Change the `if` condition to: `if list(filter(lambda x: x!='\n',candidate.contents)) == candidate.findAll('th'):` --- I guess we should move to chat if you want further discussion on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150039/discussion-between-jowens-and-vinicius-aguiar).