# Beautifulsoup does not scrape thead in tables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried multiple times to find theads in beautifulsoup but I was not successful. The code that I use is:

```
pagetable.find("thead", {'class': ''})
```

The purpose that I used a class with null entry is to make beautilsoup find process, independent of class tag.

Comment: Check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292001/detecting-header-in-html-tables-using-beautifulsoup-lxml-when-table-lacks-thea

Comment: That question is about defining thead element when there is not thead in the table. But in here, we have thead element but beautifulsoup cannot detect that.

Comment: Please provide an url or the html

Comment: No way to help without the url. My initial thought is it is a dynamic site and the table is rendered by other requests to an api. My other thought would to not include `class`. Just try: `pagetable.find("thead")` and see what that returns